# javascript increment from number to string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I parse number to string for increment? Do I have to make 2 line statement? Below code is not valid.

```
['a', 'b'].map((o,i)=>({myStr: ++i.toString()}))
```

ignore the array, it's just sample, I expect this `[{myStr: "1"},{myStr:"2"}]` where i is the index of map.

Comment: What is the input and expected output?

Comment: The input array doesn't contain numbers? What exactly would your expected output be? And why?

Comment: @LukStorms updated my answer

Comment: `['a', 'b'].map((o,i)=>({myStr: String(++i)}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap `++i`: `(++i).toString();`

```js
const res = ['a', 'b'].map((o,i) => ({myStr: (++i).toString()} ));
console.log(res);
```

You can also use template literals:

```js
 const res = ['a', 'b'].map((o,i) => ({myStr: `${++i}`} ));
 console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `++i` in a `String` constructor:

```
['a', 'b'].map((o,i)=>({myStr: String(++i)}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = ['a', 'b'];
 var newArr = arr.map((o,i)=>({myStr: (++i).toString()}))
```